# Automatic Significant Figure Counting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In converting the per-minute data to an hourly average from a CSV using Pandas, there are a varying number of significant digits in each column to be averaged. How does one have Python scan for the least number of significant digits automatically per column basis and compute the average of that hour using the number of significant digits identified?
The code I have so far is:

```
for j in range(numRows): #Begin data processing and writing to file
    columnCount=0
    writeToFile(str(df.iloc[n,0]), columnCount)
    for i in range(1,15):
        columnCount+=1
        for k in range(0,60):
            currentVal+=df.iloc[n+k-60,i]
        finalVal=currentVal/60
        writeToFile(finalVal, columnCount)
        currentVal=0
    n+=60
```

Note the three three digit rounding is an arbitrary number chosen in line 9.

Raw data to be processed:

```
...
$2021-01-27 14:21:59, 7886565, 8388606, 0.0439614, -10.3446, 28.87674, 16.75598, 85.3, 8.05, 296.10, 1.642703, 1.679849, 17.98, 1.621858, 1.515677
$2021-01-27 14:22:59, 7877479, 8388606, -0.1059374, -17.6280, 26.75315, 17.09192, 85.2, 8.05, 97.63, 1.642691, 1.665497, 12.13, 1.621841, 1.541391
$2021-01-27 14:23:59, 7865387, 8388606, -0.2734679, -19.2070, 25.73683, 17.42454, 85.3, 8.05, 68.57, 1.642685, 1.660315, 9.52, 1.621823, 1.557271
...
```

Processed data that needs to be significant figure limited:

```
...
$2021-01-27 15:21:59, 7740565.566666666, 8237031.366666666, -0.11304084333333332, -0.39772000000000013, 21.304303, 20.5396195, 85.25166666666676, 8.020999999999997, 24.097166666666666, 1.6425148833333343, 1.6490820000000002, 2.120499999999999, 1.6216546333333328, 1.6020975666666668
$2021-01-27 16:21:59, 7652499.55, 8132961.75, -0.04196207166666668, 0.15535833333333335, 18.216117500000003, 22.700520833333325, 85.2933333333334, 7.973166666666666, 7.770833333333335, 1.6424164499999994, 1.6457329666666667, 0.3581666666666666, 1.621554816666667, 1.6126316666666667
$2021-01-27 17:22:00, 7625070.9, 8096020.016666667, 0.033109383333333325, 0.13957999999999998, 17.242513666666675, 23.392457333333322, 84.7166666666667, 7.935500000000004, 6.005333333333334, 1.6423792166666664, 1.6453212833333333, 0.23183333333333342, 1.6215179999999993, 1.613404216666667
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the significant figures and formatting to the minimum  can be can be very difficult. Just thinking about a case where 1,500 is the least significant number scanned. Would you take format your final number to 0 decimals or hundreds being least significant?

However, counting the number of decimal places can be pretty easy if that works for you. One common way of counting decimal places is using the `Decimal` class from the `decimal` module.

```
from decimal import Decimal

def countDecimal(num):
    exp = Decimal(str(num)).as_tuple().exponent
    # the exponent is -1 for 1st decimal, -2 for 2 decimals
    # -1 * exp is the number of decmials
    return -1*exp


for j in range(numRows): #Begin data processing and writing to file
    columnCount=0
    writeToFile(str(df.iloc[n,0]), columnCount)
    for i in range(1,15):
        columnCount+=1
        minDecimals = 1e9
        for k in range(0,60):
            # count the decimals for this value
            n = countDecimal(df.iloc[n+k-60,i])
            # check if this has less decimals
            if n < minDecimals:
                minDecimals = n
            currentVal+=df.iloc[n+k-60,i]
        finalVal=currentVal/60
        writeToFile(round(finalVal, minDecimals), columnCount)
        currentVal=0
    n+=60
```

Comment: I don't need three figures specifically if you look in the raw data the values are of varying significant figures and I need Python to follow those significant values per column basis

Comment: I've updated my answer to include counting of decimal places. I've been going in circles thinking about significant figures. :)